# refresh javascript and css after ajax $.get_

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have global css and js which have all required definitions for me. However if i try to load in some html blocks via ajax $.get those newly loaded elements don't get proper css/js definitions. Is there any options to easily just refresh global js/css?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Maybe the error is in your css,js or html.  If you show it here, then others can look at it.  At the moment its shooting in the dark.

Comment: I found some "workaround"

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to rethink your main page design more to include resources needed.

You can append `<link>` tags to current page and use `$.getScript()` to add js and css . You would do this in the callbacks of your current `$.get`.

If you are having issues where you need to itnitalize plugins or functions or event handlers that would relate to the new html...do that in callback of `$.get()`.

Without more details about your specific issues it is hard to answer in more than general terms

Or use a more advanced dependency manager script

Comment: It is quite clear, i have one div in which i load form from some url in my page. After the form is loaded, unfortunately js which is globally loaded in to page, doesn't apply on that form.

Comment: is it all event related? If so delegate your event handling to account for elements that don't exist at run time. As far as original question being clear...it really isn't as there are a multitude of possible situations you could be referring to .... each requiring different solutions